# Angular - Call child component function from parent class

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a parents class integrated with two child templates (3 separate form details in one).
Sample form format as below:

Parent Form

- Child A Form
  (Add Child A Details) (Delete Child A Details)
- Child B Form
  (Add Child B Details) (Delete Child B Details)

Add Parent Form.

In the above sample, I was able to successfully duplicate the form elements using formarray and formbuilder. However when I click the "Add Child A Details" it should duplicate the form elements under Child B form, but in the current design it is duplicated before child B.

To meet the above requirement I tried to add the "Add" buttons of both the child functionality in the parent form and try to interact with the child class by using Input Decorator. However I'm not sure how to send a click event to the child form to trigger the function of add in the child from the parents class.

Parent form:

```
<app-child-A [addDetail()]></app-child-A>

<div class="form-group row mb-2">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                type="button" style="margin-left:10px; font-size: 12px;"
                (click)="addDetail()">
          Add Details
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Child A:

```
eventForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventForm=this.fb.group({
      eventDetails: this.fb.array([this.buildDetail()])
    }); 
  }
  get eventDetails(): FormArray {
    return this.travelForm.get('travellerDetails') as FormArray;
  }
 @Input() addDetail(): void {
    this.eventDetails.push(this.buildDetail());
  }
 buildDetail(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      eventName: '',
      desc: '',
      start: '',
      reach: '',
      transport: '',
      cost:null
    });
  }
```

I'm new to Angular please help, also if there are any other way of implementing the requirement instead of Input decorators please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: If A and B are indeed child components of parent form, you should access the A and B as ViewChildren/ViewChild. That will give you access to the public methods on the component. Using that approach, you could call the addDetails() method directly on the child component, without using inputs (which is not the correct approach for what you are trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve component interaction in angular in multiple ways.

1. Using `@Input`[property Binding], `@Output`(Event Emission)
2. Using `Rxjs` Observable/Subjects
3. Using `Local/Session/Cache Storage`.

I hope this **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpyogu?file=src/app/app.component.html)** applications fulfil your requirement.

In the above demo, i have created a shared service as below

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  public eventFormChange = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  triggerFormChange(data: any) {
    this.eventFormChange.next(data);
  }

  formChangeEvent() {
    return this.eventFormChange.asObservable();
  }
}
```

the parent component(App component)feeds updated form to the Shared Service  as below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  eventForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
private appService:AppService
) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventForm=this.fb.group({
      eventDetails: this.fb.array([this.buildDetail()])
    }); 
    this.updateForm();
  }

get eventDetails(): FormArray {
    return this.eventForm.get('eventDetails') as FormArray;
  }

  buildDetail(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      eventName: '',
      desc: '',
      start: '',
      reach: '',
      transport: '',
      cost:null
    });
  }

addDetail(): void {
    this.eventDetails.push(this.buildDetail());
    this.updateForm();
  }

  updateForm(){
    this.appService.triggerFormChange(this.eventForm);
  }
}
```

finally Child components will subscribe to the `formChangeEvent()` of shared service and rebuilds the form again as below.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  eventDetails: FormArray;
  formInfo: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private appService: AppService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.formChangeEvent().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.formInfo = res;
      this.eventDetails = this.formInfo.get('eventDetails') as FormArray;
    });
  }
```

}

parent component(app.component.html)

```
<div class="container">
<div>Child Component 1
</div>
<hr>

<child-component></child-component>

<div>Child Component 2
</div>
<hr>

<child-component></child-component>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary"
            type="button" style="margin-left:10px; font-size: 12px;"
            (click)="addDetail()">
      Add Details
    </button>
```

child.component.html

```
<form *ngIf="!!formInfo" [formGroup]="formInfo">
<ng-container formArrayName="eventDetails">
    <div *ngFor="let _ of eventDetails.controls; index as i">
        <div class="item row" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventName" class="col-form-label">Event Name</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventName" formControlName="eventName">
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="desc" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" formControlName="desc">
</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much so a clear explanation. However, my requirement is not resolved yet. The form data is still populating under Child 1.

**Requirement:**
Child 1 form
Child 2 form

Add Child 1 Detail
Add Child 2 Detail

When Add Child 1 Detail is clicked,

Child 1 form
Child 2 form
Child 1 form (should be present here).

However the duplication is still under Child 1, is there any way to achieve this?